# Can we use APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG for producers also

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have read some blocks to achieve scalability in `Kafka`. we have to use grouping concept using `application.id` and `group.id` we can make groups for consumers. same way can we make groups for producers using `application.id` and `group.id` ?

Comment: 'group.id' , 'application.id' is setting value for 'consumer group'
Producer No need 'group.id' or 'application.id'

( reference : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs )

You just need to send it with the same topic name.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka clients only uses IDs when they need to keep some state on the brokers.

As normal producers don't keep any state, they don't have any IDs (apart from the `client.id` that's used for logging).

You'll also notice that the transactional producer has `transactional.id` as it has state. http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs